# dual boot bluetooth issue: win10 & win11

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bluetooth, dualboot

I'm having some trouble to keep permanent paired a logitech k810 on a pc with dual boot (win10&11) through bluetooth.
First, i pair the keyboard on w10 for key no1: ok
second, i reboot and load w11 and i pair it for key no2: ok

when i restart, and i switch the keyboard on key no1, it start to blink like pairing was not made.
into windows, the model is still there and associated.

if i reboot and load w11, same happen.
so i lost both pairing, and i need to pair again every time when i need to use the keyboard.

does some of you face this behaviour and found a solution?
thanks so much for your support :)

Comment: Are you letting either system fully shut down (not suspending or hibernating) before starting the other system?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be [already documented](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth#Dual_boot_pairing) in the Arch Wiki.

Basically, the pairing issues occur due to different pairing keys on separate OS(s) for the same MAC.

The Arch wiki describes how to extract the keys from one Windows installation. If you can figure out changing the keys in the other Windows installation, your problem's solved.